How can a program detect whether it is running on PicoBlaze 3 or PicoBlaze 6?
On newer x86 processors there is the CPUID instruction. On older x86 processors a program can tell apart different CPU models via slight differences in bit-shifting operations. New ARM processors have special read-only registers which can be used to tell apart various processors in the ARM family. But how can a program tell whether it's running on PicoBlaze 3 or PicoBlaze 6?
